# RN Firebase dynamic link, how to resolve embedded link

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I'm scanning QR code containing FB Dynamic Link inside from withing my app. I get something like this `https://myapp.page.link/S8rq8wTHFE1KYj8D8`.
The question is how do I resolve the underlying URL/link that was used when this link was created?

Answer (score 0):

```
// add import
import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';

// use this line in your code
// `deepLink` is your `https://myapp.page.link/S8rq8wTHFE1KYj8D8`
const resolvedLink = await dynamicLinks().resolveLink(deepLink);
```

Docs: https://rnfirebase.io/reference/dynamic-links#resolveLink